# DataBinding for elements inside of a custom canvas doesn't work properly, unless parent control constructor is called

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I found some odd behavior when working with custom (overridden) canvases in WPF.  For some reason, when binding properties of a custom canvas's child, the binding does nothing.

When I switch over to using the .NET provided `Canvas` panel, then the data binding works as expected.

Here are two images (and code) demonstrating the results:

### Default `Canvas` Panel:

[image: Default Canvas]

```
<Canvas Margin="12,12,12,94" x:Name="canvas1" Background="#0E000000">
    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" X1="0" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}" Y1="10" Y2="10" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}" Height="14" Canvas.Left="0" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,41" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="-6" Canvas.Top="20" Width="279">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Width: {0}, Height: {1}">
                <Binding Path="Width" ElementName="canvas1"/>
                <Binding Path="Height" ElementName="canvas1"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="-6" Canvas.Top="49" Width="279">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}ActualWidth: {0}, ActualHeight: {1}">
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="canvas1"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="canvas1"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox1}" Content="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=checkBox1}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="78" Width="279" />
</Canvas>
```

### Custom `Canvas` Panel:

[image: Custom Canvas]

```
<local:MyCanvas Margin="12,12,12,94" x:Name="canvas1" Background="#0E000000">
    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" X1="0" X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}" Y1="10" Y2="10" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}" Height="14" Canvas.Left="0" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,41" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="-6" Canvas.Top="20" Width="279">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Width: {0}, Height: {1}">
                <Binding Path="Width" ElementName="canvas1"/>
                <Binding Path="Height" ElementName="canvas1"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="-6" Canvas.Top="49" Width="279">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}ActualWidth: {0}, ActualHeight: {1}">
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="canvas1"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="canvas1"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox1}" Content="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=checkBox1}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="78" Width="279" />
</local:MyCanvas>
```

---

After looking at this I decided to change my custom canvas so that its constructor calls the base constructor:

```
public partial class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    public MyCanvas() : base() { }
}
```

This resulted in my custom canvas behavior as I had originally expected.

### Why did this behavior occur?  What is going on inside of the base constructor that allows binding to work properly?

Thanks for the help.  Just a little curious :)

Comment: Your class is `partial`, which hints you have a XAML part of it. That's not the proper way to build a custom control. And that's also why you're getting name scope issues. Check your output window, you almost certainly have `Cannot Find Source for Binding with ElementName="checkBox1"` in the second version. This has nothing to do with constructors, but with the way you're defining your classes. BTW, subclassing WPF UI elements is discouraged unless you have a `strong` reason to. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I do have that output now that I've opened my output window.  What is the proper way to create a custom control?  If I remove the XAML code (and remove the partial class), my canvas works properly.  Could you elaborate on these "name scope issues"?

Comment: the linked MSDN article contains information about how to create a custom control. Basically you need to create a (pure C#, no XAML) class derived from an existing WPF class such as `Control` or `FrameworkElement` or an existing control / panel (depending on your needs). It is unclear to me `why` you're deriving from canvas to begin with. In regard to Name Scopes, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll read up on those articles.  The need for a custom control has very little to do with the samples posted (they are my unit testing code).  I am making a control that will display a line pattern (full of dashes/dots) when the information is set.  For example a string like this `"{0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, -0.25f}"` creates a pattern with .5 units dash, a .25 units space, a dot, then another space.  This should be a pretty handy tool. :)